# Multiple VLANs on a single port?

Tags: networking

How can I have multiple VLANs over a single port? I am NETGEAR GS108Tv2 network switch. I would like to have for example VLAN 3999 + VLAN 3998 + untagged on port 0. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, it's called vlan tagging, and this is explained her: [https://kb.netgear.com/29997/How-to-Create-Layer-2-VLANs-on-NETGEAR-ProSAFE-Switches](https://kb.netgear.com/29997/How-to-Create-Layer-2-VLANs-on-NETGEAR-ProSAFE-Switches)

Comment: Access VLANs are one vlan per physical port, trunked vlans (aka dot1q, 802.1q, encapsulated) is 1 or more vlans on a single port by way of tagging an Ethernet frame with a vlan id. The manual (http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GS108T_GS110TP_SWA_5Nov10.pdf) has a method for setting this up, page 84.